# How to call different argument from the same function in php?

Tags: php, function, variables

I need to be able to call different arguments that is stored in a function as follow:

```
function foo() {

    if( get_option( 'option_1' ) ) {
        $argument_1 = 'this one';
    } else {
        $argument_1 = 'that one';
    }

    if( get_option( 'option_2' ) ) {
        $argument_2 = 'this two';
    } else {
        $argument_1 = 'that two';
    }   

}
```

Now I need to call these arguments in different files as follow (pseudo code) :

```
<?php echo foo( $argument_1 ); ?>

<?php echo foo( $argument_2 ); ?>
```

Ho can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: So what is the issue? You're on the right track.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Sorry, please see the updated question.

Comment: Couldn't you seperate it into two functions? one returns $variable_1 and other returns $variable_2

Comment: @LiviuCostache: I think you may be thinking of this backwards.  A function doesn't *expose its variables*.  A function can *modify variables* which are in a global state and consuming code can see those modifications, or consuming code can *provide the function* with values (in the form of function arguments) and the function can *return* the calculated value.  Function's don't expose values, they evaluate to values.

Comment: @David Since you understand what I need, any suggestion are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of this backwards.  `foo()` doesn't *expose its variables* for other code to see, they are entirely enclosed within its scope.  Instead, a function can *return a value* (which may be from one of its internal variables).

When you *invoke* that function, you would provide it with whatever it needs to determine what to return.  So instead, you might have a structure like this:

```
function foo($option) {

    if( $option == 'option_1'  ) {
        return 'this one';
    } else {
        return 'that one';
    }

}
```

Then when you invoke that function, you provide it with the information it needs to perform a calculation:

```
<?php echo foo( get_option( 'option_1' ) ); ?>
```

The idea is that the entire call to the function, with the value(s) being passed to it, evaluate to a single resulting value.  So `foo( get_option( 'option_1' ) )` is logically identical to `this one` when it executes.

So you're not asking `foo` "What is the value of a variable you own?"  Encapsulation means that consuming code neither knows nor cares about the internals of `foo`.  Instead, you're asking `foo` "Here is something for you to calculate, what is the result?"

Answer (score 1):

You mean an *argument*? With a function argument (sometimes called *parameter*) you can pass a variable or value to a function and use it as a local variable:

```
function foo($localVariableName)
{
  echo $localVariableName . $localVariableName;
}

foo('abc');  // echoes abcabc
```

You can have more as well:

```
function foo($parameter1, $parameter2)
{
  echo "$parameter1 - $parameter2";
}

$a = "abc";
$x = "def";
foo($a, $x);  // echoes abc - def
foo($x, $a);  // echoes def - abc
```

There are other possibilities as well, so have a look at [PHP.net - Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Comment: thanks but, in fact I will use more than 20 parameteres so this `function foo($parameter1, $parameter2, $parameter2, ....... )` will not look so good I guess... Any suggestion?

Comment: @LiviuCostache: At that point you have a few options, none of which can be specifically recommended based on the over-simplified example in the question.  If the function is doing many different things then it's likely that it should be separated into different functions.  If it's doing one complex thing based on many different pieces of information then those different pieces of information should probably be combined into an object and that object passed to the function in its entirety.  (That object can then have internal logic which maintains how those many values relate to one another.)